# Tracking Long Animation Script

Tags: python, scripting, tracking

I wrote this script and it will track from one frame to the next.  When I put it in a loop, it no longer works.  I can hit the run key over and over again and it works perfect.  How do I make this script run until final frame?

```
import bpy
import random

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
   if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
     ctx['area'] = area
     bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(ctx)
     bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(ctx,backwards=False, sequence=False)
     bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

I have also tried the following and blender only goes forward one frame. I having trouble with changing which frame the script works on and deselecting features.

```
import bpy
import random
import math

det=0
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
for numX in range (1, 10):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(numX)
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
            ctx['area'] = area
            if det==0:
                bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(ctx)
                det=1
            bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(ctx,backwards=False, sequence=False)
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Comment: I guess you just forgot to set the frame: `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(YOURFRAMENUMBER)` which updates the scene. Why tracking only one frame is a thing?

Comment: For script markdown, select your script press `{}` button or ctrl-K.  For block scripts it indents all one right.  Please edit post.

Comment: It's working if `sequence` argument is set to `true`. However, what's your goal? Also 'autotracker add-on' might be useful: https://github.com/miikapuustinen/blender_autotracker

Comment: How do you set the sequence argument to true? Thanks

Comment: Just replace `sequence=False` with `sequence=True` @JackFeet (recommend use the `@` sign to ping someone)

Comment: **Thanks for the help** @brockmann